# MySQL taking too much time to execute

Tags: mysql, optimization, where-clause, between

My query is simple but contains lots of data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM trackhistory 
WHERE key=14846 and 
    date between "2016-11-15 00:00:00" and "2016-12-16 13:47:02"
```

I have more than 10 million rows in this table.

My table structure is :

[image]

Please help me to optimize it. Its taking more than two minutes for execution.

I have used explain for the query , but didn't get any clue.
[image]

Comment: Any indexes defined? If not, then add one for key and one for date

Comment: The possible keys being null should give you a clue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A composite `INDEX(key, date)` will be better than separate indexes.

See [*my index cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/)

Answer (score 0):

First, add an index to `Key`, and see what happens. The syntax is somehting like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `trackhistory` ADD INDEX (`product_id`)
```

Then you could add a key to `Date`, but that will add some extra effort with inserting, and will take some diskspace. This will depend on your usecases, and is impossible to say if this is a smart thing to do.

Best thing is to try out your usecases.

*(and for my sanity, if you have camel-case in your database, why not show those in your query is well. This just looks icky, having a `Date` field and having `date` in your query. I know it works, but.... )*